# Найти минимальное расстояние в графе

Tags: python

Нужно рекурсивно найти минимальное расстояние от вершины, до вершины по таблице рёбер. Вот код ввода таблицы рёбер с консоли

```
from sys import stdin


matrix = []
k = [i.strip() for i in stdin]
for i in k[:-1]:
    a, b, s = map(int, i.split())
    matrix.append((a, b, s))
matrix = list(sorted(matrix, key=lambda x: x[0]))
a, b = k[-1]. split()
```

Comment: Зачем именно рекурсивно? Вообще, есть специальные алгоритмы, которые быстро находят кратчайший путь, как например алгоритм Дейкстры, про который вам сказали в ответе. Любой из них путем определенных страданий можно привести к рекурсивному виду, но это чистое извращение, которым заниматься я вам не рекомендую. Если же вам нужен нормальный рекурсивный алгоритм, то не надуманным является полный перебор путей, но он слишком долго будет работать на сколь-либо большом графе.

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте глянуть алгоритм Дейкстры, он находит кратчайшие пути от заданной вершины до всех остальных